# Invantive Query Tool error querying NMBRS.nl

Tags: invantive-sql, invantive-query-tool, nmbrs

I want to run a query in Nmbrs.nl getting the journal information of a run.

So I selected a company by using:

```
using 111111
```

Then the following query to get the run info:

```
select *
from   CompanyRunsYear(2017)
```

This gives me a list of the runs in Nmbrs and the ids of those runs. Then I proceeded to run the `CompanyRunJournals` to get the info I need:

```
select * from CompanyRunJournals(444444, 888)
```

I got the following error message:

```
soap:Sender: Server was unable to read request. ---> There is an error in XML     
document (14, 67). ---> Input string was not in a correct format. ( 
https://api.nmbrs.nl/soap/v2.1/CompanyService.asmx)
The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.
```

Putting the CompanyID and RunID in quotes doesn't work either. Any idea what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Nmbrs.Company.CompanyRunJournalsV2` does work, it needs 3 parameters, companyid, runid and year. So for example:

```
select * from Nmbrs.Company.CompanyRunJournalsV2(111111, 444444, 2017)
```

Please note that this will return an XML file that need further parsing to use.

Comment: For further parsing, you might want to use select * from xmltable(... passing XMLFIELD ... xpath definitions per column).